# How do I fix an issue with Outlook 2016 not showing an HTML template properly?

Tags: html, outlook, email-templates

I am having an issue when I send this email template to Outlook, it adds a space after one image.  I have done some research and removed all div and floats but it still will not show this one section correctly.  It works fine in OWA, Outlook for Mac, and Gmail.  The only issue is when you view it in Outlook on a PC.  Thanks for the help.

I have found several other sites that say to change the CSS to inline, so I did that and also removed all div and floats.

The social media icons should be in line, but they show with a space after the first icon.

**Incorrect Image:**

[image]

**Correct Image:**

[image]

**Here is the code for that section:**

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="110">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <tr>
        Office of Admissions<br>
        One John Marshall Drive<br>
        Huntington, WV 25755<br>
        1-877-GOHERD-1<br>
        <a href="mailto:admissions@marshall.edu">admissions@marshall.edu</a><br>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/marshallu">
            <img alt="Facebook" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/Facebook-grey.jpg"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/marshallu">
            <img alt="Twitter" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/Twitter-grey.jpg"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/19059?trk=tyah">
            <img alt="LinkedIn" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/LinkedIn-grey.jpg"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/marshallu/">
            <img alt="Instagram" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/Instagram-grey.jpg"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/marshallulife">
            <img alt="Snapchat" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/SnapChat-grey.jpg"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try adding a width to each `<td>` element so that they all add up to the table's width (110 in your case).

Comment: Also, your markup is invalid. You are adding `<br>` tags between `<tr>` tags and there are `<tr>` tags inside `<td>` tags. I suggest reading up on basic table structure and layouts.

Comment: Adding the width didn't make a difference.  I added the <br> between the <tr> so it would add space.  Nothing else I tried would work in Outlook.

Comment: A <br> is not valid there. Use another <td> with the desired width and a transparent image of that same width instead for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good in every version of Outlook:

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="110">
  <tr>
    <td>
        Office of Admissions<br>
        One John Marshall Drive<br>
        Huntington, WV 25755<br>
        1-877-GOHERD-1<br>
        <a href="mailto:admissions@marshall.edu">admissions@marshall.edu</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 2px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td>
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="96">
        <tr>
            <td width="24">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/marshallu" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="Facebook" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/Facebook-grey.jpg" width="22">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="24">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/marshallu" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="Twitter" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/Twitter-grey.jpg" width="22">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="24">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/19059?trk=tyah" target="_blank">
        <img alt="LinkedIn" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/LinkedIn-grey.jpg" width="22"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/marshallu/" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="Instagram" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/Instagram-grey.jpg" width="22">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td width="24">
      <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/marshallulife" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Snapchat" src="http://www.marshall.edu/admissions/files/SnapChat-grey.jpg" width="23">
        </a>                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    </td>
</tr>
```

But here's the caveat, you might need to figure out how to make it look better in all mobile clients like the iPhone 6. It works, but it needs a bit more polish to work properly. I'll let you figure that out.

Good luck.